# Avoid Hessian to log into catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat, slf4j, hessian, catalina

i have a problem using Caucho Hessian. I get a lot of messages into catalina.out (tomcat) like this:

```
'Dec 20, 2012 8:33:08 PM com.caucho.hessian.io.SerializerFactory getDeserializer
WARNING: Hessian/Burlap: '...blehClass' is an unknown class in WebappClassLoader
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@f79f36b'
```

This is a problem because of the space in Gb of catalina...
I need to take this log with slf4j (i will use an upd appender to send this log to other server)

Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see on the [source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/caucho/hessian/4.0.7/hessian-4.0.7-src.jar!/com/caucho/hessian/io/SerializerFactory.java?format=ok), Caucho Hessian uses java.util.logging framework.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

So you probably want to configure the JUL bridge as explained in the official [documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

Comment: I currently have the JUL to SLF4J bridge in my app. But for some reason I can't configure the logging level in JUL after installing the bridge (it causes a  ClassCircularityError when JUL logs after the setting). Maybe it's something related with that?

Comment: I'm not an expert, maybe someone else could help you. However, my next suggestion, is to grab Caucho Hessian's sources and apply SLF4J migrator to them, to build you own version. Then you can apply standard SLF4J filters that will work.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me to turn this WARNING off is to add one line at the end of the ${tomcat_home}/conf/loggin.properties:

com.caucho.hessian.io.SerializerFactory.level = SEVERE